# yield call returning undefined rather than resolved promise value

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I am new to Redux-Saga. Below is the code for my api call-

```
const registerUserRequest = (email, password, confirm_password, country_code, phone_number) =>
{
fetch(URLs.baseUrl + URLs.signUpUrl(email, password, confirm_password, country_code, phone_number), {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': 0
    },
})
}

function* registerUserToService(action)
{
try{
    const response = yield call(registerUserRequest, action.email, action.password, action.confirm_password, action.country_code, action.phone_number);
    const result = yield response.json();   
    if(result.error)
    {
        yield put({ type: REGISTER_USER_ERROR, error: result.error})
    }
    else
    {
        yield put({ type: REGISTER_USER_RESULT, result});
    } 
}
catch(e)
{
    console.log('registerUserException', e.message);
    yield put({ type: REGISTER_USER_ERROR, error: e.message})
}
};
```

But i am getting response as undefined rather than resolved promise value and fetching result from response generates exception - **Cannot read value json of undefined.**
Would appreciate any help to understand this.

Comment: Please provide your implementation of `registerUserRequest`.

Comment: Added the implementation of 'registerUserRequest'

Comment: [the docs on call](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callfn-args) are a bit dense to parse, but they do mention that the `call` effect has different behavior depending on what your function returned. in your case, `registerUserRequest` didn't return a promise or generator, so `call` uses the return value of the function. which in this case is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return anything in your function `registerUserRequest`. If you want to get the Promise, return `fetch`

```
const registerUserRequest = (email, password, confirm_password, country_code, phone_number) =>
{
return fetch(URLs.baseUrl + URLs.signUpUrl(email, password, confirm_password, country_code, phone_number), {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': 0
    },
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fetch don't need to { }. Remove {} that surrounding fetch. Do like this.

```html
const registerUserRequest = (email, password, confirm_password, country_code, phone_number) =>
fetch(URLs.baseUrl + URLs.signUpUrl(email, password, confirm_password, country_code, phone_number), {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': 0
    },
})
```